# how to get a list of open tabs in the browser

Tags: javascript, browser, tabs

**hello**,
Is it possible to get a list of open tabs in the browser with JavaScript?
I would like to add a button to my website that alerts the titles of the opened tabs, any ideas?

thanks,
gili.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately that counts as private data... so, you'll need a browser extension for that.

Comment: Unfortunate? I'd say its rather fortunate that is the case.